# MariaDB configuration

Tags: mariadb, frappe

I run this command in my Centos 7 server:

```
frappe@vps [~/frappe-bench]# bench new-site erp.local
```

but I got this error:

```
frappe@vps [~/frappe-bench]# bench new-site erp.local
MySQL root password:
================================================================================
Creation of your site - erp.local failed because MariaDB is not properly
configured to use the Barracuda storage engine.
Please add the settings below to MariaDB's my.cnf, restart MariaDB then
run `bench new-site erp.local` again.


[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

================================================================================
frappe@vps [~/frappe-bench]#
```

When I see /etc/my.cnf file, I encounter this:

```
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

So, I look at that folder and then opened "settings.cnf" file and I have found exact the same configuration.

What else do I have to see?

Regards
Jaime

Comment: Look at that file (or directory)

Answer (score -1):

```
add the following information to /etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

then 'flush privileges;' MariaDB database
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score -1):

Please have maria db version 10.2 then site will create easily else it wont create.

Use below commands to reinstall mariadb-10.2

1. sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xF1656F24C74CD1D8
2. sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=i386,ppc64el,amd64] http://nyc2.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu bionic main'

---

3. sudo apt-get update

---

4. sudo apt-get install -y mariadb-server-10.2 mariadb-client-10.2